# Fully Delete Row in JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm using a method to delete specific lines in a JSON. The user presses a button and the button determines which line to remove. I know that the correct index is being passed in, but my problem is that when I try to remove the row it just replaces it with `null`, so there's still something there. How do I remove it entirely?

```
function removeTest(place) {
    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage["flexuralStrengthSamples"]);
    delete parsedObject[parseInt(place.data.text)];

    localStorage["flexuralStrengthSamples"] = JSON.stringify(parsedObject);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(parsedObject));

    displaySamples();
}
```

And my resulting JSON:

```
[{"Result":"Fail","Method":"T97E-v1","Beam1":{"TestingMachineId":"1","BeamAge":"1","WidthUpper":1,"WidthCenter":1,"WidthLower":1,"WidthAverage":1,"DepthRight":1,"DepthCenter":1,"DepthLeft":1,"DepthAverage":1,"MaxLoad":1,"FS":18,"PSI":"18.00000","BreakOutside":"No"},"Beam2":{"BeamAge":"","WidthUpper":null,"WidthCenter":null,"WidthLower":null,"WidthAverage":null,"DepthRight":null,"DepthCenter":null,"DepthLeft":null,"DepthAverage":null,"MaxLoad":null,"FS":null,"PSI":"NaN"},"WaitForCuring":"No","AverageOfBeams":"NaN"},null]
```

In this instance I tried to remove the second of two.

Comment: You should be able to delete a property from a javascript object in this way. Could you try putting the code on https://jsfiddle.net/ including the original JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your resulting JSON, you have an `Array []` of `Objects {}`.

In order to remove an item from an `Array` (and update it's `length`) you will have to use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

[More reading on the `delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> ### Deleting array elements
>
> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

Example

```
var arr = [ {name: "Hello"}, {name: "World"} ];

// Delete does not modify an array's length, hence the "undefined"
delete arr[1]; // => [Object, undefined × 1]

// Splice will change the contents of an array and update its length
arr.splice(1,1); // => [Object]
```